# Hot reload in Django app inside docker containers not working

Tags: django, docker

So today is my first day ever to use docker, I tried use it many times but I noticed that hot reload does not work

I opened the container using vscode and navigate through the files and tried changing files and nothing happens

here's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/project

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and here's docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    restart : always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" 
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" 
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/user/project
```

even unchecked docker-compose 2 from desktop docker and restarted the app and the containers, still nothing happens, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your directory in the container is `/usr/project`, but you map your volume to `/user/project`.

Comment: @krisskad that didn't work, got error unrecognized arguments: --reload

Comment: @HansKilian changed it to usr still same issue

Comment: The thing is, that containers are great for packaging your app so it can easily be deployed. They're not so good at doing hot reload. And they're definitely not good at doing both at the same time.

Comment: @HansKilian I solved it and answered the question, the problem now is, I thought docker can be used for development, imagine I wanted to use geodjango which requires gdal, I can't use that on windows 10 I'd need docker, so I've no idea what to do to develop such programs on windows

Answer (score 0):

I kind of figured it out, apparently I was using docker wrong
I was using `docker-compose run` instead of `docker-compose up`
and I had a typo, I copied the code to a dir `use` and mounted another dir `user` :"D